# How to rewrite 2nd order quadratic ODE into system of first order ODE as vector valued ODE u(t) = (y(t),y'(t))^t

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have the differential equation:

$y''(t) = y(t)(1-\frac{3}{2}y(t))$,

$y(0) = 1, y'(0) = 0$

How can I convert this 2nd order ODE into a system of 2 first order ODE s.t. the system can be written in $\vec{u}$ = $(y(t), y'(t))^t$? Since $y''$ turns into a quadratic function, the method in other answers in this stackexchange doesn't really work.

Comment: It is not further astonishing that a non-linear ODE can not be put in matrix form. Please show how far you got, perhaps you already had the full solution and were just unsure about its form.

Comment: Also consider the function $u(t)=y'(t)^2-y(t)^2+y(t)^3$ and its time derivative.